# Populate an object with an ObservableCollection property using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I love Linq but suck in it, I always seem to forget how to use it.
I searched but cant seem to find an answer that fits.
Here is my question

I have a two tables table_2 has the foreign key of table_1

```
table_1
----------
 - userID 
 - Name

tabel_2
----------
 - userID
 - ownID
 - codeKey
```

now i have an object(User) i want to populate with userId and name and an `ObservableCollection` of all the userID rows in table_2

Sample of the object:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long UserID { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string CodeKey { get; set; }      
    public  long OwnID { get; set; }
    public  long UserID { get; set; }
}
```

I tried doing the following; it works but am not sure if it's the right way of doing it:

```
var request = from tb1 in db.table_1
              select new User()
              {
                  Name = tb1.Name,                                  
                  UserID = tb1.UserID,

                  Messages = new ObservableCollection<Message>(
                             from tb2 in db.table_2
                             where tb2.UserID == tb1.UserID
                             select new SmsMessage()
                             {
                                 CodeKey=tb2.CodeKey,
                                 OwnID = tb2.ownID,                                                    
                                 UserID = tb2.UserID
                             })
              };
return new ObservableCollection<User>(request);
```

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Any news on this? Did you finally get it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a simpler way. If your entities have been created with those relations, you should be able to do something like this:

```
var query = from tb1 in db.table_1.Include("table_2")
            select tb1;
```

Query will be a IEnumerable with a list of objects, each one of them will contains the table_1 data and a property with its corresponding table_2 object.

So you can fill your users collection doing a simple foreach loop.

If you want to do it just with a linq query you could try it with something like this:

```
var request = from tb1 in db.table_1.Include("table_2")
                      select new User()
                          {
                              Name = tb1.Name,                                  
                              UserID = tb1.UserID,

                              Messages = tb1.table_2;
                          };


     return new ObservableCollection<User>(request);
```

Never tried it so I'm not sure about this solution 8-)